# Finding the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

In a problem, I've been given a plane $V$, the $T$ matrix of a linear transformation $(3\times3)$, and two vectors that form the basis. I've been find to find the matrix of the transformation with respect to the basis $(2\times2)$.

I'm at a loss on how to proceed for the problem. When you create a basis matrix, you get a $3\times2$ matrix. The issue I run into is that my result is a $3\times2$ matrix, which doesn't fit in the answer space given, leading me to believe this is incorrect. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you looking at the linear transformation from the plane $V$ to itself $V$ determined by the given $3 \times 3$ matrix? If so, since $V$ is two-dimensional, the result should be a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Is that what the answer space wants?

Comment: The equation for the plane is a*x1+b*x2+c*x3 = 0, in R3. I don't know how its related to the problem. The exact wording of the problem is "Let V be the plane ... Find the matrix A of the linear transformation T ... with respect to the basis ...